# jquery validation plugin doesn't work consistently

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I'm using **Twitter Bootstrap** for creating a HTML form, and JQuery validation plugin for validate it. My code is as below : 
HTML Part

```
<form id="profile_form">
    <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="firstname">firstname&nbsp;<span>*</span></label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="input-medium"
                           value="<?php echo $firstname ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="lastname">lastname&nbsp;<span>*</span></label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="input-medium"
                           value="<?php echo $lastname ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

This html uses an external javascript file, in which the validation codes resides. And the part of script file for validation is like following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#profile_form').validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element.closest('.control-group').addClass('valid').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    }); 
});
```

**Attention**: I don't have a submit button associated for this form, instead, I use a hyperlink (`<a>`) and class `button` in **bootstrap** to create a button-like item. (I don't think it will make any difference).

Now when I try to input something in the above two fields, when the input is empty, it doesn't highlight the corresponding input fields with red border instantly, can anyone tell me how to do it ? Here I clarify what I want :

Whatever the user inputs first time, the input field will not be surrounded either red / green border to show success or error. When the user click the hyperlink `<a id="finalize_btn"></a>`, the html page will jump to the first invalid input field, and highlight all invalid input fields (possibly with error message). Once the user correctly inputs something, error message will disappear, and green border appears to show success.

Hope you may understand my explanation, and thanks for all potential help !

Comment: We do not see here form with id `'#profile_form'`. It is probably missing and validation plugin binded to non existing element.

Comment: @zeliboba sorry, i just intentionally remove some code. the form **#profile_form** does exist.

Comment: okay. Then provide a link to jquery.validation plugin you are using because there are different such a plugins with same name.

Comment: @zeliboba I didn't use a CDN link, but download the source code here: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ . The version is 1.9.0

Answer (score 0):

It's not working properly because `success` is **not** the complementary callback function for `highlight`.

[As per documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions):

**unhighlight** - Called to revert changes made by option `highlight`, same arguments as `highlight`.

And `success` was failing because it cannot accept the `element` argument.  Again, as per the docs:

**success** - *If a Function is given*, its called with the **`label` as its only argument**.

So for the case of your code, you wrote `element` as the argument for `success`, but the plugin looks at this and interprets it as the name for `label`.

Use this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#profile_form').validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').addClass('valid success').removeClass('error');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Please note that there is no reason to chain multiple instances of [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) together.  Simply place multiple class names inside one `.addClass()`.

**Working DEMO with colors added to classes for emphasis:  http://jsfiddle.net/5tykD/**

Comment: @EnsomHodder, Please explain what's not working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/5tykD/

Comment: Can you specify where to download the jquery validation plugin?

Comment: @GingerHead, try the Google.  Or easier yet, refer to the SO wiki entry for the tag.